# org-mode: override buffer-local options in subtree export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have a large org-mode file containing handouts for a class. Each handout is a separate toplevel subtree (*). At the top of my org file, I have options:

```
#+OPTIONS: author:nil email:nil
```

This is followed by various handouts subtrees:

```
* Handout #1
** Some things about this handout
** Other things

* Handout #2
** Some things
** More things
```

On these individual handouts, I sometimes wish to override the `OPTIONS` settings at the top when I export to PDF. In the [export settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) section of the org manual, it suggests you can set specific export settings for a subtree, viz:

```
* Handout #1
#+EXPORT_OPTIONS: email:t
** Things
** More things
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work as I'd like. Here, for instance, when I export the subtree for Handout #1 (`C-c C-e C-s l o`) my email does appear at the top of the PDF, but then it also appears at the top of the Handout #2 PDF when I export the Handout #2 subtree.

I'd like to set persistent `OPTIONS` at the top of the file that can be turned on or off for a subtree without affecting other subtrees. How could this be done? If it can't be, is there an approach that would work similarly to what I'm searching for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `PROPERTIES` for that. Try the following:

```
* Handout #1
:PROPERTIES: 
:EXPORT_OPTIONS: email:t
:END:
** Things
** More things
```

EDITED This does work, but only when `Export` scope is set to `subtree` and not `buffer`. (Thanks to @michael-muldoon)

Comment: Yes, I've started learning about :properties: this month, and this fits perfectly into what I've been reading. Thank you!

Comment: I'm doing this (specifically changing H:1 to suppress deeper headlines) but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - are you doing subtree exporting or are you exporting the whole document? I think this only works in subtree exporting. That is a reason why it does not work on top of my head.

Comment: As described by @joon above, this does work, but *only* when `Export scope` is set to `subtree` and not `buffer`. I don't fully understand why. ```
* Handout #1
:PROPERTIES: :EXPORT_OPTIONS: email:t
:END:
** Things
** More things
```